# How to fix Error message show in always in Redirect page

Tags: php, html

this is the Redirect page code

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['msg'])) {
    echo base64_decode($_REQUEST['msg']);
}
?>
```

This code run on my action page

```
if (mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql)){
    $msg=base64_encode('Successfully Registered');
    //Redirection
    if($msg!=""){
        header("Location:../registration.php?msg=$msg");
        exit();
    }
} else{
    $msg=mysqli_error($dbcon);
}
```

actually my problem is now error messages are show in my redirect page correctly, but this message always show in my redirect page. i refresh the page that message not going But thing i'm in the register page then i go to the home page come back again register page then message in gone. how to fix this error help me place

thi is the full code in my action page

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
$msg="";
include 'db_connection.php';
$fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$nic=$_POST['nic'];
$telephone_no=$_POST['telephone_no'];
$loantype=$_POST['loantype'];
$bank=$_POST['bank'];
$amount=$_POST['amount'];
$plan_file=basename($_FILES["plan_file"]["name"]);
$payment_slip_url=basename($_FILES["payment_slip_url"]["name"]);
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//$job_description_img_url = basename($_FILES["job_description_img_url"]["name"]);
$sql= "INSERT INTO user_register (fullname,address,email,nic,telephone_no,loantype,bank,amount,plan_file,payment_slip_url,dateposted) VALUES ('$fullname','$address','$email','$nic','$telephone_no','$loantype','$bank','$amount','$plan_file','$payment_slip_url',NOW())";
//slip add START
        $folder = "payment_slip/";
        $file = $folder.basename($_FILES["payment_slip_url"]["name"]);
        //$success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["payment_slip_url"]["tmp_name"],$file);
        $ok=1;
$file_type=$_FILES['payment_slip_url']['type'];
if ($file_type=="image/png" || $file_type=="image/jpeg") {
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['payment_slip_url']['tmp_name'], $file))
{
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['payment_slip_url']['name']). " is uploaded";
}
else {
echo "Problem uploading file";
}
}
else {
echo "You may only upload JPEGs or PNG files.<br>";
//$msg=base64_encode("You may only upload JPEGs or PNG for Payment Slip");
}
//slip add END
//plan add START
$folder = "plans/";
$file = $folder.basename($_FILES["plan_file"]["name"]);
//$success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["payment_slip_url"]["tmp_name"],$file);
$ok=1;
$file_type=$_FILES['plan_file']['type'];
if ($file_type=="application/pdf") {
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['plan_file']['tmp_name'], $file))
{
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['plan_file']['name']). " is uploaded";
 }
 else {
 echo "Problem uploading file";
 }
}
else {
//echo "You may only upload PDFs.<br>";
$msg=base64_encode("You may only upload PDFs for Plan Images");
}
//plan add END
if (mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql)){
    //echo "OK";
    //$msg=base64_encode("Successfully Registered");
    $msg=base64_encode('Successfully Registered');
//}else{
    //echo "NO";
    //$msg=base64_encode("Please enter your details correctly");
//}
//Redirection
if($msg!=""){
header("Location:../registration.php?msg=$msg");
exit();
    }
}
else{
$msg=mysqli_error($dbcon);
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: use `if(isset($_REQUEST['msg']) && !empty($_REQUEST['msg'])) `. Anyway, Don't use `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: so which code i need to use

Comment: $_get- is it ok or $_Session

Comment: **What on earth** is the point of `if($msg!=""){` just after you have set `$msg` NOT TO BE EMPTY!?!

Comment: use `$_GET`. read security issues for `$__REQUEST`.

Comment: You had better show us the code being run BEFORE `if (mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql)){`

Comment: if(isset($_REQUEST['msg']) && !empty($_REQUEST['msg']))  i use this one now message noe show in the page and same error in the page

Comment: i use $_GET now message show in the page but i refresh the page message not vanished

Comment: help me place my problem not fixed

Comment: any  one know the answer for my question